# Is it possible to upload PHP files to blogspot?

Tags: php, blogspot

I am trying to create a blog using blogspot. It seems it is not possible to upload anything other than image files to blogspot. I want to upload a PHP file. I managed to upload the file to google sites, but it is coming as downloadable there instead of executing.

Is there a work-around here other than buying my own server space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a work-around here other than buying my own server space?

Nope. You can upload PHP files to those services all you want, but you'll never have them executed.

Buying your own server space is usually the best way to go.

There are free hosting offers around but I know of none that is any good, except maybe for the [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/) that is free up to a (very generous) traffic limit, in combination with [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/).  That, however, is a very specialized solution, going to be a lot of work to even get started with, doesn't support all modules of PHP, and something rather for professional applications.

Answer (score 1):

But you could simply pay some cheap hosting for PHP, and move your stuff to wordpress.

There's hundred of hostings out there for as low as $1.99 a month, and with that you can host as many PHP files as you like.

Alternatively, you could stick to blogspot, and when you want to use PHP, you can just link to your other server (the one hosting PHP).

Comment: i would like to use ajax as well and this would fail (cross-site scripting).

Comment: True, it's a security thing then. Best bet is to move out from blogspot to wordpress (or anything else) as I mentioned. As you didn't mention you wanted to use ajax, I didn't account for it.

Comment: You could use JSONP to get over the cross domain problems. But yeah, best to move away from blogspot to wordpress hosted on your own server.